# perl Forks::Super not waiting on processes

Tags: perl, fork, limit

I'm using perl's [Forks::Super](https://metacpan.org/module/Forks::Super) module to control the amount of processes I have forked at one time. Here is my code:

```
for(....) {
    my $pid = fork { max_proc => 10, on_busy=> "queue", sub => \&process_url, args=>[$url_h,$q_fh,$q_filename,$urls->{$url_h->{'url_id'}},\%fh] };
}
waitall;
```

However, the issue is that say I start off with 100 items in my loop (each of which writes out to a file), after the waitall after the loop, I may only have 60 lines written to in the file. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I am file locking, so that shouldn't be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Some debugging options: run with `$ENV{FORKS_SUPER_DEBUG}` set to a true value, or use callbacks to give feedback when a task starts, ends, or gets put on the queue.

Comment: You tell us! Is it because the write got overwritten? Did the `print` get reached? Did the `print` get reached? etc.

Comment: The print does get reached. Whenever I run this code with regular perl `fork`, it does always reach the print and writes for every process.

Comment: If you have found a bug, please report it to `bug-forks-super@rt.cpan.org` with enough information to reproduce and I'll check it out (I am the author of this module).

Answer (score 1):

I did not know too much about Forks::Super, but from the documentation I think it should be written like this:

```
$Forks::Super::ON_BUSY = 'queue';
$Forks::Super::MAX_PROC = 10;
for(....) {
    my $pid = fork { sub => \&process_url, args=>[$url_h,$q_fh,$q_filename,$urls->{$url_h->{'url_id'}},\%fh] };
}
waitall;
```

I think it would be better to write this without file handles. Using files and locks to share data between processes is not too effective.

To share data between processes in linux you could use: Cache::FastMmap. Use a known share_file and you will be good.